# Error 1774 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2008-r2, fact-table

I am trying to create a fact table in my database, and so I need to insert a lot of foreign keys. I get the following error when trying to insert a specific foreign key:

> The number of columns in the referencing column list for foreign key
>   '%.*ls' does not match those of the primary key in the referenced
>   table '%.*ls'.

I do not get why I am getting this error as the fkey has the same datatype.

Thanks!!

Comment: It says it clearly: your FK seems to contain too few or too many columns - it's not a **datatype** problem - it's a simple problems of wrong number of columns. Any FK **must** reference the **entire** PK - if that's five columns in the PK, your FK must also be five columns

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all primary key columns from the referenced table as foreign key in your destination table.

Comment: It's telling me that the original column does not have the same datatype as the one in the created tables, while it does: nvarchar (30)

Comment: Is NULL allowed in one table and not in the other or something like that?

Comment: You could paste your create scripts in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and report the link.